# linked list head re-assignment is not doing what it needs to do

Tags: c

Ok, another scrub problem. I am simply trying to replace the head of my linked list, and I'm getting behavior I don't understand. Woe.

behold,

```
typedef struct MyLinkedList MyLinkedList;

struct MyLinkedList{
    MyLinkedList * next;
    int val;
};


MyLinkedList* myLinkedListCreate() {
    MyLinkedList * head = malloc(sizeof * head);
    head->val = -1;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList* obj, int val) {
    if(obj->val == -1)
    {
        // head not initialized
        obj->val = val;
    }
    else
    {
        MyLinkedList * newHead = malloc(sizeof * newHead);
        newHead->val = val;
        
        newHead->next = obj;
        *obj = *newHead; // EVERYTHING APPEARS FINE IN THIS FUNCTION
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyLinkedList * obj = myLinkedListCreate();
    myLinkedListAddAtHead(obj, 7);  
    myLinkedListAddAtHead(obj, 9);  // BUT obj->next is not the node with 7 after returning, but 9, indefinitely.
    myLinkedListAddAtHead(obj, 11); 
    return 0;
}
```

If someone could relate to me why I want to jump off a bridge, I mean, why this assignment isn't working, that'd be swell. I suppose I could make an array of MyLinkedList in the struct, but I don't feel like it.

Comment: I suppose the reason I'd need the reference to obj is because I don't want to use a list of MyLinkedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
*obj = *newHead;
```

you just copy the contents of the newly allocated node into `obj`. You do not insert a new node into your list. Copying the contents means that `obj->next` now is `obj`, which explains your endless loop of nines.

The list is represented as a pointer to the head node in `main`. Changed to the head node of the list must be reflected in `main`, otherwise you'll just change local variables in your insertion function.

One way to update the head pointer in `main` is to pass a pointer to the head pointer. Your insertion function then becomes:

```
void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList **head, int val)
{
    MyLinkedList * newHead = malloc(sizeof * newHead);
    newHead->val = val;

    newHead->next = malloc(sizeof * newHead->next);
    newHead->next = *head;

    *head = newHead;
}
```

When you call the function, you must provide the address of the head pointer:

```
MyLinkedList *obj = NULL;

myLinkedListAddAtHead(&obj, 7);  
myLinkedListAddAtHead(&obj, 9);
myLinkedListAddAtHead(&obj, 11);
```

In `myLinkedListAddAtHead`, accessing `*head` really accesses `obj` in `main` via the pointer.

Notes:

- Please don't create "dummy nodes" for linked lists. Keep it simple: An empty list is a list without nodes, i.e. a list whose head pointer is null.
- As an alternative to passing a pointer to the head pointer, you could pass the head pointer and return the (possibly new) head. I find `head = add(head, stuff)` a bit redundant and it's easy to forget the assignment. I prefer `add(&head, stuff)`, because the `&` tells me that the head might be updated, and you can use the return value for something else.

Answer (score 1):

In below code allocating memory for `newHead->next` is not required, since you want to add element at the `Head` of the list.

```
newHead->next = malloc(sizeof * newHead->next);
newHead->next = obj;
*obj = *newHead; // EVERYTHING APPEARS FINE IN THIS FUNCTION
}
```

You can make the newly created node as `Head` and already allocated one as `Head->next` and remember you will have to return the `obj` once you are done with the updation, other wise changes wont be reflected because that function `myLinkedListAddAtHead` is called-by-value.

```
MyLinkedList* myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList* obj, int val) {
    if(obj->val == -1)
    {
        // head not initialized
        obj->val = val;
    }
    else
    {
        MyLinkedList * newHead = malloc(sizeof * newHead);
        newHead->val = val;
        
        newHead->next = obj;
        obj = newHead;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

snippet 2 pass-by-reference

```
void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList** obj, int val) {
    if((*obj)->val == -1)
    {
        // head not initialized
        (*obj)->val = val;
    }
    else
    {
        MyLinkedList * newHead = malloc(sizeof * newHead);
        newHead->val = val;
        newHead->next = *obj;
        *obj = newHead; // EVERYTHING APPEARS FINE IN THIS FUNCTION
    }
}
```

and your calls should be like `myLinkedListAddAtHead(&obj, 7);`  and change other calls also.

Comment: I agree, the assignment is not necessary, I was just double checking. It still hasn't re-assigned the obj node once it return to the main, as youv'e posted.

And I believe unless I use *obj = *newHead, that won't update the pointer, but only the obj on the call stack, which is not what I want.

Comment: that is why you will have to return `obj`

Comment: I want to re-assign it from the function

Comment: for that you have to pass address as shown in snippet 2 and change the calls accordingly